# broswer issues(ie6) for overlay images

Tags: javascript

**hi** i had browser issues(ie6)  for image overlay.the overlay is appearing in the top corner of window at around 15px.not stretching the entire screen . can anyone please guide me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Show the code you are using for the overlay.

Comment: Stop supporting IE6. It's dead. If you have users with IE6, show them a message to get a real browser

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ie7-js: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/